# Margin-top doesn't work after floated elements despite clear:both

Tags: css

Consider the following:

```
<div style='float: left; width: 50%'>content</div>
<div style='float: right; width: 50%'>content</div>
<div style='clear: both; margin-top: 50px'>content</div>
```

Why does margin-top doesn't work here? The third element is still glued to the first two elements.

Comment: Yet another margin collapsing issue... Try adding `margin-bottom` to the floats instead.

Comment: Use padding instead of margin; not always possible, depends on your design.

Comment: Add 'position:absolute' to 3rd block

Comment: Applying the same margin-bottom several times? That's inelegant. Padding worked, thanks frenchie. Although that's a quick and dirty fix. CSS really feels clumsy sometimes, so much trouble for such elemental layout stuff...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check it over here may be you need the same
https://jsfiddle.net/chaitanyaah/yychtp8t/

```
   <div style='overflow:hidden'>
     <div style='float: left; width: 50%;background:#bbb'>content</div>
     <div style='float: right; width: 49%;background:#bbb'>content</div>
    <div style='clear: both; margin-top: 0px;border:2px solid #ddd'>content</div>
   </div>
```

Comment: Works but overflow is a problem when you have popup elements involved so I avoid it at all costs now.

Answer (score 3):

You need to try to add `margin-bottom` to the floats.

Or you can try to add

```
<div style='overflow:hidden'>
<div style='float: left; width: 50%'>content</div>
<div style='float: right; width: 50%'>content</div>
<div style='clear: both; margin-top: 50px'>content</div>
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/L22qy254/)**

From the W3C specs

> #### 8.3.1 Collapsing margins
>
> In CSS, the adjoining margins of two or more boxes (which might or might not be siblings) can combine to form a single margin. Margins that combine this way are said to *collapse*, and the resulting combined margin is called a *collapsed margin*.
>
> Adjoining vertical margins collapse *[...]*

> Two margins are *adjoining* if and only if:
>
> - both belong to in-flow block-level boxes that participate in the same block formatting context
> - no line boxes, no clearance, no padding and no border separate them
> - both belong to vertically-adjacent box edges, i.e. form one of the following pairs:
>
>   - top margin of a box and top margin of its first in-flow child